# Jquery click event does not work with iFrame added to the page. Any ideas?

Tags: jquery, iframe

When I remove the iFrame it starts working again. I'm using Internet Explorer 8.

I cannot add real code right now, but it is similar to this abstraction:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="..." type="text/javascript"><script>
    <script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"><script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <iFRAME src="..." style="position:relative"></iFRAME>
    <div id="keyboard">
    <ul>
    <li>A</li>
    ...
    <li>Z</li>
    <ul>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

jQuery code looks like this:

```
$( "#keyboard li" ).click(function() {
});
```